# Javascript recursion problem

Tags: javascript, html, recursion, opacity

I am trying to write a function that will change between an array of images. What I have makes sense to me, but when I run it as it is below then the first image loads, then the second image loads at some point (the transparency doesn't change) and then nothing happens. Here is the javascript code:

```
        var image1 = new Image();var image2 = new Image(); var image3 = new Image();
        image1.src = "images/website6.jpg"; image2.src = "images/website7.jpg"; image3.src = "images/sunset.jpg";
        var images = new Array("images/website6.jpg","images/website7.jpg","images/sunset.jpg");
        /*document.slide.style.opacity = 1;
        document.slide.stylebg.opacity = 0;*/
        setTimeout(function() { fade(images,0); }, 2000);
        function delay(arr,num)
        {
            document.slide.src = arr[num % 3];
            document.slide.style.opacity = 1;
            document.slidebg.style.opacity = 0;
            document.slidebg.src = arr[(num+1)%3];
            var number = num + 1;
            setTimeout(function() { fade(arr,number); }, 2000);
        }
        function fade(arr,num)
        {
            /*alert('fadebefore ' + (document.slide.style.opacity).toString())*/
            document.slide.style.opacity -= 0.1
            /*alert('fade')*/
            document.slide.stylebg.opacity += 0.1
            if (document.slide.style.opacity == 0)
            {
                setTimeout(function() { delay(arr,num); }, 150);
            }
            else
            {
                setTimeout(function() { fade(arr,num); }, 1500);
            }
        }
```

The HTML is simple. I have two classes; `style` and `stylebg`. `style` sits in front of `stylebg` and then I change opacities and images as needed. The javascript seems logical to me, but it doesn't work as expected. Also worth noting is there are 3 comments. The first comment (line 3-4) is attemping to set the opacities to what they should be at the beginning. However, if I do this then I get even less progress than above: the first image loads and nothing else happens. The second two comments are used for debugging purposes. If I uncomment these then the image change occurs between the two alerts, which would seem to say the image change is caused by the opacity change.

So can anybody explain why it isn't doing what I expect it to? Thanks.

EDIT: Some more code:

HTML (This is the only part being affected):

```
<div style="position: relative;">
<img src="images/sunset.jpg" id="slide" />
<img src="images/website6.jpg" id="slidebg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slide{
    display:block;
    margin-left:5;
    margin-right:auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
#slidebg{
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: your JavaScript code is quite weird.. do you use Internet Explorer?

Comment: @atlavis No I don't I use Firefox. This is my first time writing javascript so that's probably why it is so weird. I'd be happy for you to explain what is weird about it.

Comment: At a first glance you need to add some vars for your setTimeout, i.e. `var tid1,tid2,tid3;` and later use `tid1= setTimeout(....) ` for the first use of setTimeout and so on

Comment: @mplungjan why would he need to keep track of the timeout handles?  The timeouts are not being cancelled, so what's the point?

Comment: @mplungjan Why do I need to do that? I thought you only needed to do that if, later on, you might want to cancel the timeout? Or is it just a kind of clean code thing to do?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you would get in trouble if you do not split the timeout handles. It can be that it is no longer so, but I have always done this and it fixed numerous issues in browsers past.

Comment: @mplungjan no, there's really absolutely no reason to keep track of those if the timeouts aren't going to be cancelled.  The return values are just numbers, after all; they're not magic.

Comment: Hmm, you might be right. But I seriously remember issues in the past.

Comment: Shouldn't you do something like `document.getElementById('slide').style.opacity` instead of `document.slide.style.opacity`?

Comment: Yes he should, but now it works if you use name instead. (and I am sure it works in most browsers with ID too)

Comment: Update - it works in most browsers except chrome to use document.slide when slide is the id and not the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering for formatting's sake. I have not debugged to see what would work, but this makes more sense to me

If you want to use ID, use document.getElementById, if you want to use name, use document.images[imgname] or document.imagename
You are mixing names and style too. document.slide.stylebg.opacity and such

This does something. Not sure it is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/EcShW/2/

```
<div style="position: relative;">
<img src="images/sunset.jpg" id="slide" name="slide" />
<img src="images/website6.jpg" id="slidebg" name="slidebg" />
</div>


    var images = []; // can be more elegant, but this is simpler
    images[0]=new Image(); images[0].src="images/website6.jpg";
    images[1]=new Image(); images[1].src="images/website7.jpg";
    images[2]=new Image(); images[2].src="images/sunset.jpg"; 
    var tid1,tid2,tid3
    tid1=setTimeout(function() { fade(images,0); }, 2000);
    function delay(arr,num)
    {
        document.slide.src = arr[num % 3].src;
        document.slide.style.opacity = 1;
        document.slidebg.style.opacity = 0;
        document.slidebg.src = arr[(num+1)%3].src;
        var number = num + 1;
        tid2=setTimeout(function() { fade(arr,number); }, 2000);
    }
    function fade(arr,num)
    {
        document.slide.style.opacity -= 0.1
        document.stylebg.style.opacity += 0.1
        if (document.slide.style.opacity == 0)
        {
            tid3=setTimeout(function() { delay(arr,num); }, 150);
        }
        else
        {
            tid3=setTimeout(function() { fade(arr,num); }, 1500);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried it exactly as you said and it hasn't change anything. Also, as said below, I understand I have mixed id/names a bit but why does the following work? http://jsfiddle.net/E3H8G/1/

Comment: You have TYPOS in your original code. 
`document.slide.stylebg.opacity += 0.1` should be 
`document.slide.style.opacity` or `document.slidebg.style.opacity`

Look at my fiddle. It does work http://jsfiddle.net/EcShW/2/

Comment: Ah thank you very much, I see where most of the problem was. It still doesn't work but I think I should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: There is no looping - you need to reset the counter when it is higher than images.length

Comment: It is (num+1)%3 so shouldn't that reset itself?

Comment: Hmm, I am tired ;) Not a regular way to do this but quite clever now I think about it

Comment: So another unsolved problem is if I uncomment the first comment then the javascript seems to stop. If I put an alert immediately after those comments then it is never reached, and I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: I have selected this as the answer because it was what made me realise my mistake. I have gotten it working and if anyone is interested they can view what I got here: http://jsfiddle.net/x2mej/1/. Also it would be nice if you could this link to this answer so if anyone looking here can find what I've done easier.

Comment: great. You could update your post with an update or post the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just refer to page elements by "id" value like that; you have to use "document.getElementById()":

```
 var slideElement = document.getElementById('slide'), slidebgElement = document.getElementById('slidebg');
```

Then you'd work with "slideElement.style" etc. instead of "document.slide.style".

Comment: Of course he can. `<img name="slide" ` will answer to `document.slide`

Comment: @mplungian - look again - his images don't have "name" attributes!

Comment: @mplunjan [here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LTag6/) to make clear that `<img>` elements with **just** "id" values and no "name" value cannot be referred to as members of the "document" object.

Comment: @Pointy, I don't think this is the problem. If I change the opacity using document.slide.style.opacity = 0.5 then the opacity changes. If you try this yourself and it still doesn't work then I'll be willing to try your way, but for me it works.

Comment: @Pointy, why does this change the opacity if I can't refer to it as I have been above? (I hope that doesn't sound sarcastic): http://jsfiddle.net/E3H8G/1/

Comment: It sure doesn't change it in Chrome.

Comment: @paul - yes you can. however you shouldn't. As I mentioned, use document.slide if the image has a name, document.getElementById if you use id. @Pointy: your fiddle works fine in Fx4

Comment: @mplungjan but your example uses "name" attributes, not "id"; that's the whole point.

Comment: @pointy - look again in IE and Fx: jsfiddle.net/xZB4z - only to prove a point(y)

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT2**

**It works for me (chromium)**

```
var images = new Array ();
images[0] = new Image();
images[0].src = "images/website6.jpg";
images[1] = new Image();
images[1].src = "images/website7.jpg";
images[2] = new Image();
images[2].src = "images/sunset.jpg";

function delay ( arr, num )
{
  slide.src = arr[num % 3].src;
  slide.style.opacity = 1;
  slidebg.style.opacity = 0;
  slidebg.src = arr[(num+1)%3].src;
  var number = num + 1;
  setTimeout(function() { fade(arr,number); }, 2000);
}

function fade(arr, num)
{
  if ( slide.style.opacity == 0 )
  setTimeout(function (){ delay(arr, num); }, 150);
  else
  {
    slide.style.opacity = (slide.style.opacity*10 - 1)/10 ;
    slidebg.style.opacity -= -0.1;
    setTimeout ( function(){fade(arr,num);}, 1500 );
  }
}
fade (images, 0);
```

---

**AHA!**

`<img id="img_id"/>` we can get by `document.img_id`, even in chromium

---

---

OK, OK, removed links to this **[WE TEACH YOU TO FAIL AT WEB DEV](http://w3schools.org)** site..

Comment: His use of setTimeout is fine.  Also, [w3schools should be avoided](http://w3schools.com).

Comment: `window.setInterval()` fits better (it's name) IMO. Anyway, I'm REALLY curious why w3schools should be avoided.

Comment: I've never found there something that work wrong or do not work at all. It has never wasted my time.

Comment: @atlavis Sorry I linked to the wrong site (w3schools instead of what I'd intended, [the site "w3fools"](http://w3fools.com) ). You can look at the stuff they've compiled and see whether you agree.

Comment: @Atlavis I completely agree with @pointy just look here [horrible example with an eval'd function](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_stop) - they perpetuate bad habits